# Roots of a Cubic Equation depending on the value of $a$

Tags: functional-equations, cubics

Here is the question I am currently working on:

> Show that if $a$ is real, then the equation $x^3+ax+2=0$ has three real roots *if and only if* $a\leq-3$

I know that if the discriminant, call it $\Delta$, of a cubic equation of the form $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$ is positive, then the cubic equation must have three distinct real roots. I am planning to split this problem, into $3$ separate cases, one where $a<-3$, $a=-3$, and $a>-3$. I'm not entirely sure if this is even the right approach or am I just making things more complicated than what it should seem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) of a cubic of the form $x^3+px+q=0$ is $\Delta=-4p^3-27q^2$.

So the discriminant of your equation is:
$
\Delta=-4a^3-4\cdot 27
$
and the equation has three real solution iff 
$$
-4(a^3+27)\ge0 \iff a^3\le -27  \iff a \le -3
$$
(for $a=-3$ two solutions are coincident).

Comment: How did you get $4 \cdot 7$?

Comment: Ahh nevermind your edit made it clear.